# How to untar without leading slash /

Tags: tar, slash

I have tar file, 11.2.0.4.tar, of the following path: /oracle/product/11.2.0.4. I want to untar it in a custom folder, for example /export. I tried with the -C option, but didn't work - the shell hangs for a few seconds, then the prompt is returned without any result.

```
tar -xvf 11.2.0.4.tar -C /export
```

So, how do I extract without the "/" so I would have /export/oracle/product/11.2.0.4? I read there is an option only when taring, but not when untaring.

Comment: If I create a tar file with leading '/'s and then try to extract it, it says `tar: Removing leading `/' from member names`. What version of tar are you using on which platform?

Comment: It sounds like tar is treating `-C /export` as a pattern to search for in the tar file. Are you sure the hyphen you're using a proper hyphen and not a non-ASCII version? Also, see previous comment about version and platform.

Comment: SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-23 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
How can I view the tar version? tar --version doesn't work. And yes, I am sure it is a proper hyphen.